# Applications always were started automatically

Tags: windows-10, window

Using windows 10, but calculator, photo, video applications always were started automatically. Help me. I want stop it. Thanks

Comment: Always *were* started or always *are* started?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Task Manager**, then click `More details` at the bottom left corner of the window. Then go to the tab `Startup` and select the programs that you want to disable by clicking `Disable` at the bottom right corner, you can always `Enable` them again.

Hopefully this helped you. If the programs aren't on the list, warn me!